# Is this notation for the improper uniform prior correct?

Tags: bayesian, prior

Can I write: $\mu \sim U(0,\infty)$ ?
Or do I have to use the notation $p(\mu)  \propto 1$?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you please explain me what the notation $p(\mu) \propto 1$ exactly means?

Answer (score 5):

The U(0,∞) distribution does not exist, so you cannot use this notation.

The notation $$p(\mu)\propto 1$$ signifies that the density of the prior distribution against the Lebesgue measure on $(0,\infty)$ is constant. There is no way one can set a specific constant value, since the density cannot be integrated, so the notation states that it can be any constant. The value of the constant does not and should not matter in any aspect of Bayesian inference. If it does you cannot use this constant prior.

Comment: An alternative attitude towards notation is that if it is unambiguous, clearly defined, and expressive, then why not use it?  So if the OP explicitly defines "$U(a,b)$" to be a "uniform improper prior" when either or both of $a$ or $b$ is infinite, it would seem that the nonexistence of an actual distribution with those limits would be relevant only insofar as it proves the notation is unambiguous!

Comment: I disagree: this notation encourages the (over)interpretation of non-informative priors as extended distributions.